# Rpyc: one client to many servers

Tags: python, asynchronous, client-server, rpyc

How do I connect the same client to many servers?

I've tried:

```
c0 = rpyc.classic.connect(ip0)
async_update0 = rpyc.async(c0.modules["some_module"].some_function)
async_result0 = async_update0() 

c1 = rpyc.classic.connect(ip1)
async_update1 = rpyc.async(c1.modules["some_module"].some_function)
async_result1 = async_update1()
```

But only the later one is actually being done when I do async_result0/1.wait().